# Serializing the XDocument Response

Tags: c#, json, .net, linq

Code :

```
var xml = XDocument.Load(JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonReader(
Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(responseString.ToString()), new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas()));
```

The above response is producing the below output as i am completely new to JSON

Current Format:

```
<root type="object">
<errors type="array">
<item type="object">
<errorCode type="string">err.func.illegalVCD</errorCode>
<errorMessage type="string">Vcd not recognized</errorMessage>
</item>
</errors>
<error_reference type="string">rrt-020ed13861dc37b7a-a-eu-17894-12597647-1</error_reference>
</root>
```

But I want the Output as below :
Expected output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<results xmlns:xsd=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema xmlns:xsi=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance>
<root type="object">
<errors type="array">
<item type="object">
<errorCode type="string">err.func.illegalVCD</errorCode>
<errorMessage type="string">Vcd not recognized</errorMessage>
</item>
</errors>
<error_reference type="string">rrt-020ed13861dc37b7a-a-eu-17894-12597647-1</error_reference>
</root>
</results>
```

Please help me with serializing the response to get the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

the namespace xsd is never used in the xml, so why should that appear?

To have a results element you could probably do something like this:

```
var xml = XDocument.Load(JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonReader(
Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\"results\": { " + responseString.ToString() + " }"), new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas()));
```

or

```
var xml = XDocument.Load(JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonReader(
Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("{\"results\": " + responseString.ToString() + " }"), new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas()));
```

depending on the format of your JSON.

Or you could create a new XDocument with

```
new XDocument(new XElement("results"))
```

then add the root xml element of your first document to the root element of the second

Comment: Hi @cddimari Could you please help me what i need to add in the results place  that you have mentioned in Double Quotes     ----Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\"results\": { " + responseString.ToString() + " }"),